# javax.crypto.BadPaddingException : pad block corrupted

Tags: java, android, encryption, md5, des

While decrypting a string value we are sometimes seeing this BadPaddingException. Not all the time for exactly the same values but just sometimes. The encryption seems to work just fine... Seems like other have had the same issues sometimes as well, although their answers didn't work for me...

```
private String encrypt(String value) {
    try {
        final byte[] bytes = value != null ? value.getBytes(UTF8) : new byte[0];
        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
        SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(SEKRIT));
        Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
        pbeCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new PBEParameterSpec(Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID).getBytes(UTF8), 20));
        return new String(Base64.encode(pbeCipher.doFinal(bytes), Base64.NO_WRAP), UTF8);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
private String decrypt(String value) {
    try {
        final byte[] bytes = value != null ? Base64.decode(value, Base64.DEFAULT) : new byte[0];
        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
        SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(SEKRIT));
        Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
        pbeCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new PBEParameterSpec(Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID).getBytes(UTF8), 20));
        return new String(pbeCipher.doFinal(bytes), UTF8);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine aside from being very insecure (MD5 and DES, really?). How are you transmitting the ciphertext?